# git log: what is meaning of commit ... → (origin/branch_name) ←

Tags: git

I have this output when run `git log`

```
commit 9211...11c39 (HEAD -> branchname1, origin/branchname1, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 2...d f...a
Author: UserName <thename@example.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 17 02:11:14 2022 +0900

    Merge pull request #111 from org/feature_branch

    Blah blah blah

commit 3211...11f34 (origin/feature_branch)
Author: UserName <thename@example.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 17 02:05:43 2022 +0900

    bug fix

commit 3ad1...1aed4
Merge: 50...bc 0a...88
Author: UserName <thename@example.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 16 03:26:17 2022 +0900

    Merge pull request #110 from org/feature_branch

    blah blah blah 

commit a3ee...3a5b6 (origin/feature_branch)
Author: UserName <thename@example.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 3 14:25:00 2022 +0900

    bug fix
```

Some of commits has only commit ID: `commit 3ad1...1aed4`, but some of commits has a `(origin/feature_branch)` addition.

What is meaning of `(origin/feature_branch)` addition?

That was not my commits so I don't understand clearly what actions was did here and why commits are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing you that the tips of those other branches are also at that commit.

Imagine that you're on master, and then you create three new branches at that location (but you don't add any commits). You'll have 4 branches whose tips are all at the same commit.

Comment: Close. But there isn't really such a thing as a "tip of a branch". A branch is just a name for _one commit_ and that's all it is. So Git is simply reciting all the branch names associated with each commit. So: "You'll have 4 branches whose tips are all at the same commit." Not quite. You'll have four branch names pointing to one and the same commit. Or, reversing our point of view, one commit will have four names. No "tips" please!

Comment: In other words that showing current state of outdated branches? In my example upper `origin/feature_branch` state is behind one commit and another one is behind 3 commits, right?

Comment: @rzlvmp It is *not true* that these identifiers are evidence that your local repo is out of date. It has nothing to do with freshness. It is pretty common for multiple branches to all point to the same commit. As matt says, this is git telling you that each of these branch names points to this commit, according to your git database. One common scenario: someone merges a branch to `master`, but does not delete the just-merged branch; the merge commit will list both master and the just-merged branch (and will continue to do so until master or the branch gains commits, or the branch is deleted).

Comment: @matt: there is a "tip commit"; see the definition of "branch" in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary).